# Array Combination need as like below

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have 2 arrays `$finalTitle` and `$finalDescription` i have used `array_merge` and create main array as `$finalResult` and output as below

```
[
    {
        title: "ABC's Script"
    },
    {
        title: "DEF's Script"
    },
    {
        title: "GHI's Script"
    },
    {
        title: "JKL's Script"
    },
    {
        description: "My Name is&nbsp;ABC, I am living in&nbsp;Rajkot, I can able to speak&nbsp;English Language."
    },
    {
        description: "My Name is&nbsp;DEF, I am living in&nbsp;Surat, I can able to speak&nbsp;Hindi Language."
    },
    {
        description: "My Name is&nbsp;GHI, I am living in&nbsp;Vadodara, I can able to speak&nbsp;Tamil Language."
    },
    {
        description: "My Name is&nbsp;JKL, I am living in&nbsp;Ahmedabad, I can able to speak&nbsp;Gujarati Language."
    }
]
```

I want array result as below in final output. I want `title` and `description` in single array instead of different array name.

```
[
    {
        title: "ABC's Script",
        description: "My Name is&nbsp;ABC, I am living in&nbsp;Rajkot, I can able to speak&nbsp;English Language."
    },
    {
        title: "DEF's Script",
        description: "My Name is&nbsp;DEF, I am living in&nbsp;Surat, I can able to speak&nbsp;Hindi Language."
    },
    {
        title: "GHI's Script",
        description: "My Name is&nbsp;GHI, I am living in&nbsp;Vadodara, I can able to speak&nbsp;Tamil Language."
    },
    {
        title: "JKL's Script",
        description: "My Name is&nbsp;JKL, I am living in&nbsp;Ahmedabad, I can able to speak&nbsp;Gujarati Language."
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done with below code.

```
foreach ($finalTitle as $key => $value) {
    $finalResult[] = array('title' => $value['title'], 'description' => $finalDescription[$key]['description']);
}
echo json_encode($finalResult);
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than merging the two arrays, could you not do a nested *for* loop so the data at each point in the array is returned then concatenate the result?

```
 I = 0;
 j = 0;
 For (i = 0; 0 < finalTitle.length; I++){
       For (j = 0; 0 < finalDescription.length, I++) {
           finalTitle + ‘/n’ + finalDescription
       }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that relationship always holds.

Give this a try:

```
$split = count($array)/2;

$array = array_chunk($array, $split);

for($i = 0; $i < $split; $i++){

  $results[] = array(

    'title' => $array[0][$i]['title'],
    'description' => $array[1][$i]['description']

  );


}


echo '<pre>';
print_r($results);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => ABC's Script
            [description] => My Name is ABC, I am living in Rajkot, I can able to speak English Language.
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => DEF's Script
            [description] => My Name is DEF, I am living in Surat, I can able to speak Hindi Language.
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => GHI's Script
            [description] => My Name is GHI, I am living in Vadodara, I can able to speak Tamil Language.
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [title] => JKL's Script
            [description] => My Name is JKL, I am living in Ahmedabad, I can able to speak Gujarati Language.
        )

)
```